# Need to verify the older way of defining handler mappings using mvc:annotation-driven?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In an app I'm looking at I find this in the dispatcher xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Am I correct that this is the Spring 3 way of defining handler mappings (url routes). One of the controllers in the app looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/order")
@SessionAttributes(OrderController.ORDER)
public class OrderController
{
 //...
```

I assume that the line

```
@RequestMapping("/order")
```

is the actual definition of the handler mapping for this url route.

Am I correct that the older way of defining this handler mapping would have been with one of:

- `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`
- `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`
- `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`
- `CommonsPathMapHandlerMapping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `<mvc:annotation-driven />` is a convenience option for configuring Annotation-driven controllers. It configures special `HandlerMapping`s and `HandlerAdapter`s.

See [the section in the Spring reference manual about `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) for a full list of what specifying this actually does.

As an alternative, you could always specify the `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, etc. beans yourself manually.